# Transform Tick to Date in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, jwt

I'm trying to check the expiration date of a JWT token and everything I tried is not getting me the right date.

```
"exp": 1522210228 => real answer => Wednesday, March 28, 2018 12:10:28 AM
```

I've tried thoses libs and I didn't get those to work...

1. https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/master/src/jwthelper.service.ts
2. https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode

## 1

```
const helper = new JwtHelperService();
const decodedToken = helper.decodeToken(this.authentificationInfos.token);
const expirationDate = helper.getTokenExpirationDate(this.authentificationInfos.token);

console.log(expirationDate); => null?
```

## 2

```
import * as decode from 'jwt-decode';

const token = decode<{ data: { exp: number, iat: number, iss: string, nbf: number, username: string } }>(this.authentificationInfos.token);
const date = new Date(token.data.exp);
console.log(date); => Sun Jan 18 1970 09:50:10 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

const d = new Date(0);
d.setUTCMilliseconds(token.data.exp);
console.log(d); => Sun Jan 18 1970 09:50:10 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Here is the complete token:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7InVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYmlsb2RlYXV2aW5jZW50QG91dGxvb2suY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTIyMjA2NjI4LCJpc3MiOiJtbnAuY29tIiwibmJmIjoxNTIyMjA2NjI4LCJleHAiOjE1MjIyMTAyMjh9fQ.1WRlQatauXw2HEWj9B9VL6fIVR-4nAoKuWvkS4_m86k
```

https://jwt.io/ is decoding the token and the exp displayed is correct.

How can I get the real date from token.exp?

Comment: `token.data.exp*100`. Milliseconds are off, because `token.data.exp` is in tenths of seconds.

Comment: *1000 but i got it by yout milliseconds call! thx

Comment: My bad, `token.data.exp*1000`. I guess that time is just seconds.

Comment: @Vince did my anwer below  answer your question? Would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: did you solve it? i am facing the same issue. jwt.io is good! but my date! is wrong

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The timestamps in JWT are UNIX timestamps counting from 01.01.1970 00:00 UTC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4 explains that a numeric date is used for the exp claim (and also for the nbf (not before) and iat (issued at) claims)

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-2 defines the numeric date:

> A JSON numeric value representing the number of seconds from
> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time, ignoring
> leap seconds.

```
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
var jwt = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7InVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYmlsb2RlYXV2aW5jZW50QG91dGxvb2suY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTIyMjA2NjI4LCJpc3MiOiJtbnAuY29tIiwibmJmIjoxNTIyMjA2NjI4LCJleHAiOjE1MjIyMTAyMjh9fQ.1WRlQatauXw2HEWj9B9VL6fIVR-4nAoKuWvkS4_m86k";

const token = jwtDecode(jwt);
const d = new Date(0);
d.setUTCSeconds(token.data.exp);
console.log(d);
```

output:

> 2018-03-28T04:10:28.000Z

Use `d.getHours()`, `d.getMinutes()` etc. to get your local time.

Comment: this was not working with our code, i was getting 1970 date

Comment: Was using `new Date(exp)` and getting a 1970 date, but using `setUTCSeconds` as described works well.

Answer (score 16):

Since it is a value of seconds from epoch, all you have to do is multiply `exp` by 1000.

See demo below.

```js
const jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IllvIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.9xA3RWBjEdQmUFlf5E7fLrR8Xi36ogcjGrOdkL6DA3Y";

const decodedJwt = jwt_decode(jwt);

console.log( new Date(decodedJwt.exp * 1000) );

// output: "2018-01-18T01:30:22.000Z"
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jwt-decode@3.1.2/build/jwt-decode.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting the answer in the year 1970, you probably aren't multiplying the decoded exp value with 1000 which is required. You need to pass the exp date in milliseconds into the new Date() object when creating it.

```
const token = jwtDecode(jwt);
const d = new Date(token.exp * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

const token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IllvIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.9xA3RWBjEdQmUFlf5E7fLrR8Xi36ogcjGrOdkL6DA3Y"
let _expData = jwt_decode(token || '{}')
let _exp = token.exp * 1000
let _date = new Date(_exp)
console.log(_date)
```